# Perl: Static vs Package methods

Tags: perl, static, package

I need to create a package which will be used by other developers.
What is the best way to implement static methods?
For static (class) methods I must expect 1st parameter $class, and method must be called as a class method:

```
My::Package->Sub1();
```

From the other hand I can write a "regular" package subroutine (no $class parameter expected) which will perfectly do the same, but needs to be called differently

```
My::Package::Sub1();
```

So, basically there is no difference from the business functionality perspective (at least I don't see it, except package name availability through the first parameter), but 2 different ways to implement and call. Kinda confusing.
Which way should I use and when? Is there some rule?
Also, should I check if method was called as I expected (static vs package)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a functional point:  If a 2nd Class is create that inherits from `My::Package`, `Child::Class::Sub1()` will be undefined, and if `Sub1` is written as a non-OO subroutine, `Child::Class->Sub1()` will ignore the fact that it's being called from `Child::Class`.

As such, for the sake of the programmers using your module, you'll want to make all of the subroutines in a Package/Class respond to a consistent calling structure/methodology.  Your module should either be a *library* of subroutines/functions or a *class* full of methods.  If part of it is OO, make it all OO.  It is possible to create subroutines to behave in a mixed mode, but this complicates the code unnecessarily, and seems to have gone out of fashion on CPAN.

Now if there is truly no reason to distinguish between `My::Package->Sub1()` and `Child::Class->Sub1()`, then you can feel free to ignore the implicit class name parameter you'll be passed.  This doesn't mean you shouldn't *expect* that parameter or that you should encourage a non-OO call format in an OO Module.